# How to break operation of if else in vb6

Tags: vb6

Hello i have this code in vb6 and i want the code to break operation if i click the cancel button but i cant seem to do it i searched online and found nothing, is it possible to do it? This is the code below:

```
if value <= temp then
    if (msgbox("Select an option", vbOKCANCEL + vbExclamation, MSG_TITLE) = vbCancel) Then
        'i want the code to break here and stop as it is to do nothing
    else
        'extra code
    end if
end if
```

Any idea how can i do that i think vb6 doesnt have `BREAK` as a function

Comment: Try the `STOP` statement for VB6 if you actually want to pause the running program.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/stop-statement  If you want to stop the whole program, you can use `End`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
if value <= temp then
    if msgbox("Select an option", vbOkCancel Or vbExclamation, MSG_TITLE) = vbCancel Then
        ' Do nothing
    else
        ' extra code
    end if
end if
```

```vb
if value <= temp then
    if msgbox("Select an option", vbOkCancel Or vbExclamation, MSG_TITLE) <> vbCancel Then
        ' extra code
    end if
end if
```

```vb
if value <= temp then
    if msgbox("Select an option", vbOkCancel Or vbExclamation, MSG_TITLE) = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    else
        ' extra code
    end if
end if
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if value <= temp then
    if (msgbox("Select an option", vbOKCANCEL + vbExclamation, MSG_TITLE) = vbCancel) Then
        goto keluar
    else
        'extra code
    end if
end if
keluar:
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.